# AngularJS: Creating a directive for converting a string to a Date on the fly

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

Angular UI Bootstrap changed the way of what the datepicker expects as `ng-model` in some version after 1.13.0. Before it was fine to give it an ISO date string, now it wants a `Date` object.

I consume ISO date strings from my API though, so I have to

- convert them into `Date` objects before giving it to the datepicker and
- convert them back to an ISO date string when storing it.

In the past I used a directive like this:

```
function DateObjectDirective() {
  const directive = {
    restrict: "A",
    require: ["ngModel"],
    link(scope, element, attributes, controllers) {
      const ngModel = controllers[0];

      ngModel.$formatters.unshift(value => {
          let output = null;

          if(value) {
            output = moment(value).toDate();
          }

          return output;
      });

      ngModel.$parsers.unshift(value => {
          let output = null;

          if(value) {
            output = moment(value).format();
          }

          return output;
      });
    },
  };

  return directive;
}
```

This no longer works though, as the following error is reported:

> this.activeDate.getFullYear is not a function

My guess is that the datepicker still uses the string as reference. Is there any other way I can convert before giving my data to the datepicker?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the directive I posted does indeed still work. The only problem was the **order in which AngularJS evaluated the directives**.

For example:

```
<input ng-model="someDateString" uib-datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" woo-date-object>
```

In my case, `woo-date-object` was always evaluated **before** `uib-datepicker-popup`. The result was that the datepicker has always pushed its own formatter on top of `ngModel.$formatters`, thus eliminating the possibility for me to intervene.

The solution is to give the own directive a higher priority. UI's datepicker doesn't have one set, so anything above 0 (which is the default) works:

```
{
  restrict: "A",
  require: "ngModel",
  priority: 9999,
  link(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
    ngModel.$formatters.push(value => {
        let output = new Date();
        if(value) { output = moment(value).toDate(); }
        return output;
    });

    ngModel.$parsers.push(value => {
        let output = null;
        if(value) { output = moment(value).format(); }
        return output;
    });
  },
}
```

Comment: I think if you named your directive uibDatepickerPopup you wouldn't even need to define your directive (woo-date-object) on the element.

Comment: @RobJ `uibDatepickerPopup` is already defined by AngularUI Bootstrap. Also I like it more to be able to use it when I need it, not all the time.

Comment: Angular allows you to extend directives by using the same name and setting the priority for the order of execution.

Comment: @RobJ I see, nice to know, I didn't know that. But I still consider it not being ideal, as I probably don't want to use the custom behavior every time. Thanks anyway!